# Can we lose messages in Kafka Streams if we add new partitions?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Say for example, I have 4 partitions.
When a message **msg1** of ***key 101*** is put into **partition 1** (*out of 4*) and **is not consumed *yet***. Meanwhile a new partition is added making total of 5 partitions.

Then the next message **msg2** of ***key 101***, goes to 4th partition (say for example) because the `hash(101)%no_of_partitions=4`.

Now, in the streams API, whenever a message is consumed by its key, the partition 4 will be accessed for the key because that is the partition it gets when it computes the `hash(101)%no_of_partitions` and therefore it gets the **msg2** of ***key 101*** in **partition 4**.

Now, what about the **msg1** of ***key 101*** in **partition 1**? Is it consumed at all?

Answer (score 3):

You won't loose data, however, depending on your application, adding partitions might not supported and will break your application.

You can add partitions only, if you application is stateless. If your application is stateful, your application will most likely break and die with an exception.

Also note, that Kafka Streams assumes, that input data is partitioned by key. Thus, if the partitioning is changed, even if the application does not break, it will most likely compute an incorrect result, because adding a partition violated the partitioning assumption.

One way to approach this issue is, to reset your application (cf ). However, this implies that you loose your current application state. Note, that resetting will not address the problem about incorrect partitioning though and your application might compute incorrect results. To guard agains the partitioning problem, you could insert a dummy `map()` operation that only forward the data after you read data from a topic, because this will result in data repartitioning if required and thus fix the key-based partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

The **msg1** of **key 101** in **partition 1** will be consumed.

In Kafka Streams, you do not "consume a message by its key". Every message in every partition will be consumed. If someone should filter on the key, it would be in the code of the Kafka Stream App.

Comment: That means it will query all the partitions for a particular key, rather than *blindly* going by the partitioning logic?

Comment: @Java Partitioning logic only applies at the producer. The Consumer group coordinator would need to rebalance the Streams app when new partitions are added, but that doesn't mean messages won't be consumed from any new partitions, once assigned to a consumer instance

Comment: @cricket_007 then what about the order of the messages?

Comment: @Java they are consumed in the order they were produced... I've already answered your previous questions about that. Besides, if you had 5 partitions and 5 separate streams apps, no app would be able to see the data that others are. If you have 4 or less instances, 2 partitions are randomly assigned to one instance... My point there is that you shouldn't be reliant on which data is read by which instance or thread, and assume you can do immediate analytical types of work on it without grouping or reparationing downstream of the consumer poll loop

Answer (score 0):

It will be consumed, but order is not guaranteed. Be sure that application logic is idempotent. One possible solution is to go through intermediate topic with more partitions. `KStream#through` will help you to produce and to consume with a single instruction. The method does exactly the same thing and returns a `KStream`. In pseudo code:

```java
   .stream(...)

   // potential key transformation
   .through("inner_topic_with_more_partitions")
   .toTable(accountMateriazer)
```